# Email Regex is extracting some dummy data

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I am trying to extract Emails from the HTML body. I tried a lot of solutions on the internet to extract Emails but it also extracts some dummy data. 
i.e

```
[ 'bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1',
'popper.js@1.12.6',
'bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1' ],     
['core-js@2.6.9'],
[ 'michael@2x.jpg',
'michael@2x.jpg',
'chuma@2x.jpg',
'chuma@2x.jpg',
'nathan@2x.jpg',
'nathan@2x.jpg',
'kyle@2x.jpg',
'kyle@2x.jpg']
```

The regex I used to extract emails are here:

First One

```
   /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

Second One

```
  /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi
```

I used the *match* function to extract Emails

```
 const emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/

var result = body.match(emailRegex)
```

Can someone help to make better Regular Expression to desired emails?

Comment: Why are you trying to extract email addresses from an HTML body? Surely there is a better way than a regex of achieving what you're after, assuming you own the site in question.

Comment: other ways ?? better than regex?

Comment: @Emma I tried all solutions from this link but none of fork for me.

Comment: @Emma I updated, one more case is fail

Comment: @Emma I updated [this](https://regex101.com/r/McM2vT/3)

Comment: [Updated link](https://regex101.com/r/McM2vT/4) @Emma

Comment: Have a look at [TLDs](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is overly complicated. You can break the problem into smaller chunks to make it easier to solve.

First parse the HTML and find the node that contains text such as `<p>` elements, then run your regex over the contents of those. You will have a much easier time that way.